# How to revert git clean

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit, git-clean, git-untracked

I have a git flow question.

I've worked in my code on a local 'developer' branch in git. Then after work was finished I did an add of all changed files and after that I committed it on my local branch 'developer'. Then I wanted to checkout to my local 'master' branch to pull the new version from remote 'master' branch to after that merge the new remote version with mine from the 'developer'.

But the checkout to the local 'master' from the local 'developer' was aborted because of some untracked files. Unfortunately I used `git clean -f -x -d` to clean my repository and this deleted all the files even the committed ones. I thought this will only delete the untracked ones. However I'm able to see my commit on git extensions tool but by using `git status` it shows that a lot of files were deleted.

I know that a clean is not revertable, but as I did a commit before cleaning up may I somehow "ignore" the clean I did by reverting to my last commit I did on my local developer?

Hopefully there is a possibility.

Many many thanks in advance.

EDIT: I did the things provided and it worked. I am at my old commit which has the changes made. But unfortunately the git clean deleted some folders which are required for the project. Now some build paths are missing which are required. This folders are empty ones but still needed for project flow. How can I readd this empty folders deleted by the clean I made? A pull from origin/master didn't work. There the folders are available.

Regards,
alfi92.

Comment: Can you use `git reflog`? Is there anything in there that would help?

Comment: If you know the sha code of the last successful commit in the developer branch. Just do a reset to that sha code.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options:

1. `git reset --hard <commit-SHA>` This will move your branch pointer to `<commit-SHA>`. Anything staged with `git add` gets thrown out. Modified files that have not been staged also get thrown out. This is the biggest hammer you can wield. In effect, you have re-cloned the repository.
2. `git checkout -- .` This will revert all modified files found starting from the current directory. Deleted files not marked for deletion with `git rm` will be restored. This will ***not*** remove things from the staging area you have previously staged with `git add`. If all you desire is to restore previously committed files, I would start with this.

Comment: Thanks. Your first option worked well. but now some folders which are needed for the class path are gone because those was empty ones. Do you know how to get these folders again?

Comment: Empty folders are not recorded in git. For example, you cannot 'git add' an empty folder and then 'git commit' that. If you want 'empty' folders to be part of your repository, the folder needs some kind of placeholder file inside it to be aded/committed to your repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the sha code of the last successful commit in the developer branch. Just do a reset using that sha code. This should reset all the pointers to the old successful commit and you will get your files back.

git reset --hard shacode(of the successful commit)